# Postgres complains about non-existant constraint

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I am in the progress of migrating our database schema in postgresql and i get this error in Django(1.11.11):

```
        django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: constraint 
"djstripe_charge_account_id_597fef70_fk_djstripe_account_id" for relation "djstripe_charge" already exists
```

However executing `ALTER TABLE djstripe_charge DROP CONSTRAINT djstripe_charge_account_id_597fef70_fk_djstripe_account_id ;` in `psql` gives the following error:

```
ERROR:  constraint "djstripe_charge_account_id_597fef70_fk_djstripe_account_id"
 of relation "djstripe_charge" does not exist
```

I verified in psql with `\d djstripe_charge` and it doesn't show up on the relations list

In django, the error occurs(90% sure) in the migration code:

```
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='charge',
        name='account',
        field=models.ForeignKey(help_text='The account the charge was made on behalf of. Null here indicates that this value was never set.', null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='charges', to='djstripe.Account'),
    ),
```

Why does Django complain about this?

Comment: Still no index with `djstripe_charge_account...` and no column called account_id.

Comment: You seem to have hit [this issue](https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe/issues/616).